# Sub Panel Question

Tags: electrical-panel

Does anybody see problems with this setup?  It is a sub panel (not my first service disconnect).  It looks to me that the neutral comes from the main panel and connects to the bar; the same bar appears to be grounded.  I know code has neutral and grounds running on connected to separate bars in sub panels; that's why I'm not sure what's going on. [image]

Comment: I notice not many grounds,  are the ungrounded “GFCI’s” connected by conduit? What year was the panel installed. What state / jurisdiction? We’re the GFCI’s added later ?

Comment: These pix have been gallery'd into one JPEG.  That always means the resolution is smashed down to "very low" and it's hard to see stuff. Better to post the raw pix.  If the size is too large, use your image software to reduce the JPEG "quality" not the resolution.  Q=3 is fine for web.

Comment: Where is this panel located relative to the main panel/disconnect? In the same building, or a detached outbuilding?

Comment: Can you post a second photo that clearly shows where the feeder enters the panel at the bottom left? It's pretty congested down there, and we can't really see all the details.  Also: is the incoming feeder conduit metal or plastic?  (The bushing makes me think it's metal, but I can't tell for sure)

Comment: It is located in a detached garage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have correctly identified the problem. I think whoever installed this originally (a) didn't understand the difference between main panel and subpanel with respect to ground/neutral bonding and (b) may have thought that since there were two vertical bars next to each other that they were 1 neutral + 1 ground and mix/match OK. However, depending on when it was installed, it may have been code-legal at the time, in which case you normally don't have to fix it.

In reality, I suspect the reason for the two bars is because of half-size breakers. Since neutral wires are normally one per screw, if you had a panel filled with a lot of half-size breakers then you would need both bars simply to have enough neutral screws.

So the basic answer is to get an appropriate *accessory ground bar* for the panel and mount it properly and move the ground wires to the ground bar.

**However, you may have a bigger problem.** Based on the diagram, you appear to have a *12 space/24 circuit* panel. But based on the way the breakers are installed, it appears to be a *16 space* panel. That may be just some confusion, or an incorrect label, or a swap of panel guts without changing the label. But it may be a sign of a serious code violation.

Upload a picture of any documentation, labels, etc. so we can figure it out.

Comment: Without the date knowledge the ground and neutral were commonly combined and not until the NEC 99 code change 4 wire was added / required, in other words this part was probably fine in some jurisdictions up to 2005 longer in 3 or 4

Comment: This answer is way off base as it fails to consider that 3-wire feeds to sub panels were legal for many decades.

Comment: @nobody After Ed Beal raised that issue, I modified my answer. I think it is still relevant because (a) we don't know the age, (b) there are other similar situations where it may be relevant (and SE is meant to be a long-term storehouse of useful Q&A) and (c) I raise other concerns as well.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that panel to be pre-1999 code requirements. if so When that panel was installed that was totally code compliant.

There is no requirement to change existing installations unless a change of occupancy (occupancy like residential that is converted to a doctors office or dentist require updates)

The one thing that would concern me is the white taped green. This would have me thinking mid 70’s but it was allowed in some occupancies for quite some time.

The other is SO cord??? It looks like so but may be UF as larger sizes are black if rubber it is cordage and that is not allowed.

Asking for anything without more information may bring up more than you want.

Comment: I found a cert showing it was inspected in 1991, I can't find building permit but I'd venture to guess it was wired in 1991.

Comment: So this would make it totally code compliant the way it is. It looks like there is a ground rod the stranded copper coming in. It looks like a 3 wire (the 3 blacks bitten left) but if conduit it could be considered 4 and it could be changed if you wanted but if no 4th wire or conduit it would be best to leave as is.

Comment: Thanks, for the assistance.

Comment: Ekleebert, thanks are given by upvoting or acceptance of an answer the green check mark.  Lately many comments have been being removed I had one with a code ref supporting another users answer removed recently. Accepted answers help others with the same issue find the answer.